# Are there canonical test cases for testing of pricing engines

Tags: backtesting

Short intro: We are developing pricing engines for the calculation of market risk in a Solvency II solution, including bonds, callable bonds, cds, options, futures and so on. Are there any canonical test cases which the engines have to solve?

Comment: hello Owe. what is the purpose of a pricer of futures? how does that work?

Comment: In Solvency II you have to consider the effect of interest rate changes on every price, so we take the usual formula Future = Spot * exp(-rt).

Comment: Surely that should be F=S*exp(rt), i.e. no minus?

Comment: The danger of working from memory. Indeed we are using discreet returns, and have Price = Spot*(1+r*t)